# what is the correct way to compare the return of a function

Tags: c

A simple question. I have a function `int function(void)`. Are the following statements the same:

```
a. if( function() == somevalue ) //somevalue is integer
b. if( (function()) == somevalue )
c. if( (ret = function()) == somevalue ) //where ret is an integer
```

Comment: Be more specific. Obviously, they all differ. Which one in particular you use depends on your specific case.

Comment: @Downvoter - I'm guessing that a & b are functionally identical (and would probably create exactly the same code during compilation)

Comment: @KevinDTimm I was referring to the lexical difference, but yes, I would agree. As a matter of principle, though, the OP should narrow down what he/she actually wants because "same" is a pretty broad term.

Comment: What type is `somevalue`?  If it were a `double`, depending on `FLT_EVAL_METHOD`, things may differ, though not likely.  But that is an odd corner case.

Comment: **Moderator Note**: [Be Nice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice)

Comment: To those that are trying to close the question: What is the *unclear* in my question? If i said *is BOOL the same with unsigned char* would it be *unclear* too? Ofcource, they lexically differ! I dont mind closing it. But it would be unfair for the person who get the answer.

Comment: What is unclear from a not yet close voter: 1) [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40940406/what-is-the-correct-way-to-compare-the-return-of-a-function#comment69092361_40940406) remains unanswered.  2) [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40940406/what-is-the-correct-way-to-compare-the-return-of-a-function#comment69092614_40940406) "same"-ness issue and 3) This [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40940406/what-is-the-correct-way-to-compare-the-return-of-a-function#comment69092733_40940406)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All three of them are functionally equivalent as far as comparing the return value is concerned.

(a) and (b) are equivalent whereas (c) lets you save the return value from `function` (in `ret`) if you need later. Unless you need the return value of `function()` later for some other purpose, I'd recommend using (a).